# Run JBoss on all interfaces (was: "Open port 8080 on Ubuntu")

Tags: ubuntu, port, webserver, jboss

I'm running the JBoss webserver on my ubuntu (10.10 64bit) machine and I'd like to access it from another machine.

If I open localhost:8080 in the browser on my local machine it works. However, from the remote machine I can ping my ip address, but I can't access port 8080. I also can't seem to see port 8080 by running netstat -pan.

How can I open up port 8080 to the world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure your server isn't configured to listen only on localhost (lo) interface? Look for its configuration and have it listen on all interfaces.

The default startup script for Jboss has the following line to specify which IP address Jboss should bind itself to

> JBOSS_BIND_ADDR=${JBOSS_HOST:+"-b $JBOSS_HOST"}

You can either edit this line or if you are running [u|l]inux system, you can add the following line above this line

> JBOSS_HOST=`hostname`

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much. Looks like you need to run jboss with the command 'bin/run.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -c web'

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you haven't enabled the Firewall?

```
sudo ufw disable
```

This might be a security risk you can choose to ignore. If you want to configure your firewall later, check [this documentation of ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW).

Comment: I ran 'sudo ufw status' earlier and it gave me 'Status: inactive', thanks...

Comment: Now that's kind of strange. Sorry that didn't work out.

Comment: No worries, could have been the firewall quite easily, thanks for the help!